# Python взаимодействие двух процессов в фоновом режиме

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
cmd = ["python3", "/home/user/python/python0.py"]
cmd1 = ["python3", "/home/user/python/pytho2.py"]


p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=p1.stdin, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

data = p1.communicate()
```

В данном примере я передаю поток вывода одной программы другой но взаимодействие не происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите сделать. Я так понял, Вы хотите `stdout` от одной команды перенаправить в `stdin` другой команды.

## stdout.py

```
print(f"ohayo, ya {__file__}")
```

## stdin.py

```
a = input()
print(f"Hello, im {__file__} and i got")
print(a)
print("from my stdin")
```

---

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
a = Popen(["python", "stdout.py"], stdout=PIPE)
b = Popen(["python", "stdin.py"], stdin=a.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
print(b.stdout.read().decode().strip())
```

### Вывод

```
Hello, im stdin.py and i got
ohayo, ya stdout.py
from my stdin
```